# displaySize = invalid initializer

Tags: size, cocos2d-iphone, initializer

I have a method where I'm taking a screenshot, but there's 2 problems with it. For the 2 lines

```
    CGSize displaySize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] displaySize];
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
```

I get the warning Invalid initializer for displaySize, and also CCDirector may not respond to '-displaySize'
Oh and I'm using cocos2d...

This is the entire method

```
-(UIImage *)screenshot {
CGSize displaySize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] displaySize];
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
GLuint bufferLength = displaySize.width * winSize.height * 4;
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc (bufferLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, displaySize.width, displaySize.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);

int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * displaySize.width;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate (displaySize.width, displaySize.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc (bufferLength);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, winSize.width, winSize.height, 8, winSize.width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, displaySize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, displaySize.width, displaySize.height), iref);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef] autorelease];

NSString *file = @"GameOver_Screenshot.png";
NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
return image;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "CCDirecrot.h" is not imported to the source file

EDIT:
What version of cocos are you using?
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_director.html
Here is no displaySize method for example

Also try to write this
`CCDirector *director = [CCDirector shareDirector];`
and check with debugger director is correct.
If director is correct then check with debugger what values are put in winSize and displaySize or when the application is crashing.

Comment: I didn't import it before, but importing it now didn't change anything :(

Comment: By the way, all this code is in the AppDelegate...does that make a difference?

Comment: I added that initialization of director, but what do you want me to do with it? How do I check the values?
Sorry for the late response, I didn't see that you updated your answer

Comment: try putting breakpoint at the next line and when it trigger - hover director variable with a mouse and check if it is nil or not. If everything is correct it should not be nil

Comment: Is just simply doing CGSize displaySize; ok? It gets rid of the warning :P If not, what do you mean by hovering the variable? And I should set a breakpoint for the line ____?
Thanks for your continued support :)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html read this article. And stop your program with the breakpoint to if director variable is correct

Comment: What is 'director' doing? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: just to check it's ok with a debugger